# How to color this region in this code by the tkz-tab package?

Tags: tkz-tab

With the code below, I'll get
[image]

But I want this output:
[image]

**How can I do that?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{h style/.style = {solid,fill=red!50}}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {solid}}
\tkzTabInit[color,espcl=1.5]%
{$x$ / 1,$g(x)$ / 1}%
{$-\infty$,$1$,$2$,$+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{,h,d,-,z,+}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{t style/.style = {solid}}
\tkzTabInit[color,espcl=1.5]%
{$x$ / 1,$g(x)$ / 1}%
{$-\infty$,$1$,$2$,$+\infty$}%
\tkzTabLine{,h,d,-,z,+}
\draw[fill=red!50] (T12) rectangle (N21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Enchors of the tabular (`T12` and `N21`) are  mentioned  in the manual of `tkz-tab`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution but could you please explain what are `T12` and `N21`? What do they mean?